# How to exclude absolute path in StackTrace from .NET exception

Tags: c#, .net, exception

.NET program, when there is exception throw out, the StackTrace will include absolute path where the program be build. e.g. build on my laptop, then it will show the absolute path on my laptop

how can that absolute be excluded in StackTrace?